# Does LEGO ship to my country?

Tags: shopping

Today I wanted to order some LEGO sets from official LEGO Shop to get the exclusive LEGO fountain. But when I went to checkout, my country wasn't available in the shipping list. I live in Slovakia. When I read the "Shipping & Handling", it wasn't stated that they don't deliver to my country. I'm very confused. What should I do?

Comment: LEGO not sending to my country too, I find two options to solve the issue (workarounds):
  **1.** Send from USA - you can send the package via external company that give you an address in USA
  **2.** Buy from another online shops, like  bricklink - http://www.bricklink.com/v2/main.page - you can also find shops close to your country.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe that LEGO currently ships to Slovakia via shop.LEGO.com. You can see the list of available countries in the "Regions" drop down in the top right on shop.LEGO.com:

[image: available regions]

I'm sure you are aware that there are plenty of other places to order LEGO that would ship to your country, but that doesn't help you if you're mostly interested in getting the current fountain promo as a freebie with some other things you are ordering.

Answer (score 1):

If you know any third party shipping  companies or have a trustworthy friend out of country, have TLC ship to them, and then said friend/company will send it to you through the regular mail. It will take a while, but it insures you get all of what you want.